# How to put on the server MVC web-app

Tags: angularjs, spring, server, cloud

I have created MVC web-app (AngularJS + Spring), as course work. Now I need to put it on the cloud server (aws amazon or something else). Please, help me to find good tutorial for it.

Comment: You can't find any tutorials about spring and aws with a quick google search?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why you want to host your course work over cloud.I assume that you are well aware of "[When to use cloud platform](http://www.itworld.com/article/2832631/cloud-computing/when-to-use-cloud-platforms-vs--dedicated-servers.html)"

An abstract idea about AWS you can get [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/web-app-hosting-intro.html)

You can do SO/google for specific case

Comment: Just for expirience. Thanx for adivce!